# PHP+MySQL Printing query results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, echo

I used to print MySQL query results like this:

```
$query="SELECT fname,lname,email FROM users";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $num=mysql_numrows($result);
    mysql_close();
    $i=0;
    echo '<table BORDERCOLOR=black>';
    ?>
    <tr>
    <th>Vardas</th><th>Pavarde</th><th>E-Mail</th>
    </tr>

    <?php

    while ($i < $num) {
        $field1=mysql_result($result,$i,"fname");
        $field2=mysql_result($result,$i,"lname");
        $field3=mysql_result($result,$i,"email");

        echo "<td>";
        echo $field1; 
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $field2;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>"; 
        echo $field3;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

But this time I have to use something different , and I was wondering how can I  print out my results when using the function/query shown below:

Query code (in 'class DB'):

```
function query($querytext) {
        $rs = mysql_query($querytext, $this->_link);
        if($this->_debug) {
            $this->addDebugMessage("\t<tr>\n\t\t<td class=\"debug_nr\">".$this->_queryCount++."</td>\n\t\t<td class=\"debug_queInfo\"><b>Query: (".@mysql_num_rows($rs).")</b></td>\n\t\t<td>" . htmlspecialchars($querytext) . "</td>\n\t</tr>\n");
            if(mysql_error() != '') {
                $this->addDebugMessage("\t<tr>\n\t\t<td class=\"debug_nr\">".$this->_queryCount++."</td>\n\t\t<td class=\"debug_queInfo\"><b>Error #".mysql_errno($this->_link)." :</b></td>\n\t\t<td>" . htmlspecialchars(mysql_error($this->_link)) . "</td>\n\t</tr>\n");
            }
        }
        if($rs) {
            $num_rows = @mysql_num_rows($rs);
            if($num_rows) {
                if($num_rows > 0) {
                    $rsarray = array();
                    while($line = mysql_fetch_array($rs , MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                        array_push($rsarray, $line);
                    }
                    mysql_free_result($rs);
                    return $rsarray;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                if(mysql_affected_rows($this->_link) > 0) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

(in 'class User')

```
function findUser($phrase){
        global $DB;
        $results=$DB->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname LIKE '%'$phrase'%' OR lname LIKE '%'$phrase'%' OR email LIKE '%'$phrase'%'");
            return $results;
    }
```

In index.php (what do I use to print this out?):

```
$USER->findUser("john");
```

or maybe it should be

```
$results= $USER->findUser("john);
```

OR

```
$results=DB->findUser("john");
```

Comment: Are you sure that findUser function is actually doing anything? It looks like it doesn't return the query result.

Comment: I am not sure. I used the same function with $DB->query("DELETE..."), and that worked, I guess I need a "return $query" in this one?

Comment: Yes, I think findUser should `return` what it gets from `$DB->query()`. For DELETE queries, there is no result so you wouldn't necesarily need a return.

Comment: Also, be aware that your query function (among a handful of weirder things) returns results as an array of arrays, not as a MySQL result. This means that you don't use mysql_numrows and mysql_result to loop through the data, just a simple foreach or something like that.

Comment: I have edited the return into the code, also, does that mean I won't be able to print it out nicely into a table like with the first method?

Comment: This is all built around the hazardously out of date `mysql_query`, an interface that's being removed from PHP. Is this part of a legacy application or is it new code? It also looks like you're failing to [properly escape](http://bobby-tables.com/php) values like `$phrase` which can lead to severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: It's just a quick test actually, nothing serious, it won't be uploaded anywhere, I'm just trying to learn, it's all on localhost. Would you know how do I print what I get from that query though?

Comment: I think you may be closing your DB connection prematurely; that could play a role.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have a typo

```
function findUser($phrase){
        global $DB;
        $DB->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname LIKE '%'$phrase'%' OR lname LIKE '%'$phrase'%' OR email LIKE '%'$phrase'%'");
    }
```

There is extra quotes in your query.

```
function findUser($phrase){
        global $DB;
        $DB->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname LIKE '%$phrase%' OR lname LIKE '%$phrase%' OR email LIKE '%$phrase%'");
    }
```

Comment: Do I need to move towards comments part. As this will not address the OP's problem?

Comment: I wasn't sure, because the original format is '%keyword%', and since I use one from a function I thought it should be '%'variable'%'. Anyways, any help about the printing part?